# Accessing a member function from other class

Tags: c++, function

I am fairly new to C++ and have been wondering if I can make a call to a member function of class A from a member function of class B.

Object of class B is created inside of class A.

```
class A{

   func_A();
}

A(){ // constructor A

   B b; // object of Class B 
} 

class B{
    func_B();     // stuff
}

func_B(){

  // would like to call the member function (func_A) of class A
}
```

Is there a way that I can call the member function of Class A (func_A) from member function of Class B.

Thanks.

Comment: The default access specifier in a `class` is private. You also need a member of `B`.

Comment: In order to call a member of class A you need an object of type A to call it on. Which object would you like to use? The one that contains the B in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your functions public and add a B object to A as a member variable.

```
class A{
   B b;
public:
   void func_A();
}

class B{
public:
    void func_B();
}

void B::func_B() {
    func_A();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I feel that it does provide an answer.

Comment: When I validated your post, I did not see your introduction line. Without it, the answer would have been of little use to a beginner. Sorry if I missed it.

Comment: No, you didn't miss it. I added it because of your comment. It was lazy of me to just dump the code.

Comment: All is well that ends well, then :)